# PyQt4: White flickering only on transparent buttons in the GUI bug

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04**, **Python 2.7** with **PyQt4.11**.
I have a video viewing GUI (using `GraphicsScene`) with some buttons on it (using `setGeometry(...)`)

I would like the buttons to be transparent to hide as little of the video as possible. I'm using the following line of code:

```
self.button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: transparent }")
```

When I open it, the buttons start flickering with white bars when the mouse hovers on them.

[gif that show the flickering](https://gph.is/2RjQXZN)

The default setting of the button also has this problem. The problem goes away if I set a specific colored background (but only with 100% color - any other percentage of opacity brings it back).

I also tried:

```
self.button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover, QPushButton:disabled:hover, QPushButton:hover:!active")
```

and:

```
QPushButton:hover { background: transparent; background-color: transparent; }
```

and:

```
 self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
 self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

No luck with any of them. Attached is a video of the phenomenon.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue/knows how to fix it?
(Sidenote - sadly moving over to Python3/Qt5 isn't an option)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: your image/video has a purple color that is annoying to see.